# How to get Mail.app raw message in the Automator?

Tags: applescript, automator

This is an cross-post, because i'm not sure where it really belonging. It is programming question, but apple specific question too.

Here is the stackoverflow link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970080/how-to-get-mail-app-raw-message-in-the-automator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set theSource to {}
    tell application "Mail"
        repeat with aMessage in input
            set end of theSource to aMessage's source & return
        end repeat
    end tell

    return theSource as text
end run
```